# Comparing two list<T> objects and Updating the first object with second object using linq in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, list, linq

I have an Excel file with the set of records and I have a database called UserTable with a set of records. what I'm doing is comparing both the records with the field called UserId. there are some fields with null values and some with values in UserTable. If I compare the Excel with the database(UserTable) record it has to fetch the updated one with values in all fields.
I have changed

I tried this:

```
    public class UpdateData
    {
        public void Update(List<UserTable> users, List<UserTable> mappeddata)
        {
            //var result = from values in mappeddata join values2 in users on values.UserId equals values2.UserId select values;
            var valuestobeupdated = from m1 in mappeddata
                          join m2 in users on m1.UserId equals m2.UserId
                          where m1.ManagerUserId != m2.ManagerUserId
                            || m1.Department != m2.Department
                            || m1.Title != m2.Title ||  m1.Email != m2.Email || m1.FirstName != m2.FirstName    
                          select m1;
            Console.WriteLine("Updated");

        }
    }
```

but this is case sensitive for example if UserId=A24070 in users && UserId=a24070 in mappeddata it doesn't match, same goes with other field.
Is there a way to make it case insensitive
for example I did this in another statement
`var userIdnotinTable=userIdinExcel.Except(userIdinTable, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`
is there any example available for this? or is there any other way to do this?

thanks!!!

Comment: I would take a look into this article from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings#case-insensitive-ordinal-comparisons

Comment: I checked the article but i want to change the entire list<t> object into case insensitive while comparing.methods in the article need sorting in advance which will hit my performance

Comment: The article has a whole section on comparison - did you read the article? Perhaps [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/performing-culture-insensitive-string-comparisons) on string comparisons would be more helpful? Perhaps `String.Compare(s1, s2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0` is what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always `.ToLower()` both sides of the equation, but depending on the amount of data it could bring a noticable performance impact.

#### Edit:

When considering performance, it is important to understand if the task is executed periodically or just once (or a couple of times) manually:

Converting two string of ~8 characters to lowercase x 200,000 is still not a great feat for a modern system, but if this task is to be executed, let's say, every 10 minutes, then the additional ms would start to add up and be noticable in CPU time (which further down the line means more server costs).

If you need to do this once - absolutly go for it, I'd say.

Comment: I need to consider performance too I have around 2 lakh rows

Comment: What's a lakh? Please ensure you use terms familiar to the wider audience

Comment: 1 lakh=100,000 in Indian numbering system

Comment: Thank you for telling me that I will change that I am new here

Comment: @Sapris I edited my answer to better explain the performance topic

Comment: Why don't you want to update case sensitive changes though? Anyways, the way to do it is not toLower but "someString".Equals("SomeString", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)); ToLower must do a full case conversion which you don't need if you check character by character

Answer (score 0):

Note that data sanitization is an important part of performance.

Please note that your real issue is the lack of standardization in data available in both datasets.

What you really should be doing is to write whatever inefficient logic you need to "match" records, but then update the DB with "fixed" User ID (e.g. update DB record from a24070 to A24070.)

This can be a separate, one-time script you would run (and pay the performance penalty once) and your recurring job's comparison logic would not need to deal with casing issues.

This also assumes that you identify the system that's polluting database with lower case data and get that code fixed, so that bad data won't keep coming in.

In short, you're focusing on the `wrong problem`.